# Authenticate user using LinqtoLDAP

Tags: c#, linq, active-directory, windows-authentication, linq-to-ldap

I'm using Linq to LDAP, and was wondering if there's a way to authenticate against the AD using Linq to LDAP,

Maybe something to the effect of this

```
var user = context.Query<User>().FirstOrDefault(u => u.SAMAccountName == "user123" && u.Password == "1234");
```

Comment: Indeed, maybe. Have you tried it? What were the results?

Comment: I can't do that because there's no Password attribute in the AD, or at least I don't think it'll be exposed in that manner

Comment: I used an AD viewer program, and there's no password attribute, unlike the sAMAccountName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passwords cannot be returned by a search in AD.  You are only allowed to modify them over SSL.  You can try to issue a Bind request using an LdapConnection, but that doesn't require LINQ to LDAP, only SYstem.DirectoryServices.Protocols.

```
var connection = new LdapConnection("localhost");

try
{
    connection.Bind(new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain"));
}
catch (LdapException ex)
{

}
```

Is there a reason why you can't use NTLM or Kerberos?